# R fill a matrix in a loop

Tags: r, matrix

The data I have is for 8 variables named `s1`, `s2`... `s8` for 122 days (which goes from 152 
till 273 day of the year) and for 11 years (from 1997 till 2007). Here is the data:

```
#generate sample data
set.seed(1)
var<-as.data.frame(cbind(runif(1342),runif(1342),runif(1342),runif(1342),runif(1342),runif(1342),runif(1342),runif(1342)))
names(var)<-c("s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","s6","s7","s8")
day<-rep(152:273,times=11)
year<-rep(1997:2007,each=122)
dat<-as.data.frame(cbind(day,year,var))
```

What I want to do is this:

1) Select the first variable `s1`

2) For the year 1997, add the value of `s1` of the 122 days

3) Do this for all the years till 2007

4) Select the second variable `s2` and repeat

Ideally I want to save the outputs in the 3rd column of the following matrix

```
#create a matrix to store data

mat<-matrix(nrow=88,ncol=3)
var<-c("s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","s6","s7","s8")
col1<-rep(var,each=11)
col2<-rep(1997:2007,times=8)
mat[, 1:2] <- cbind(col1, col2)
```

For e.g. after summing the 122 days of s1 for 1997, the sum should be stored in `mat[1,3]`. And so on. I created the following loop to do this

```
#create a loop
for (i in 3:10){
  dat1<-dat[,c(1:2,i)]  #selects the s1 data
     for (j in 1997:2007){
         year<-dat1[dat1$year==j,] # selects the data of 1997 from s1
         total<-sum(year[,3]) #sums up the 122 days of s1 for the year 1997
         mat<-total?????????????????
 }}
```

Now I am stuck in the last part. How do I assign `total` to `mat[1,3]` and the next total to `mat[1,4]` and so on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dplyr option of user2100721 is better than the following loop but if you wanted to know how to do exactly what you stated:

```
for (i in 3:10){
  dat1<-dat[,c(1:2,i)]  #selects the s1 data
     for (j in 1997:2007){
         year <- dat1[dat1$year==j,] # selects the data of 1997 from s1
         total <- sum(year[,3]) #sums up the 122 days of s1 for the year 1997
         mat[mat[,1] == names(dat)[i] & mat[, 2] == j, 3] <- total
 }}
```

Basically, you can assign to a specific cell of the matrix if you want. I select here the line by matching the line to the correct column `(names(dat)[i])` and the correct year.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))
```